# Google Sheet Custom Function works on one sheet, fails on another - same permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have two sheets, similar columns, where a custom function returns a value from subsequent cells in the row. Both sheets are in the same folder and I have the same edit permission on both.

On one sheet, the function works perfect. On another sheet, the function fails with a

> "You do not have permission to access the requested document."

In most cases this error either indicates you are accessing another doc/sheet or the person running the script does not have access to the current (active) sheet. I believe it can also happen if attempting to use .setValue().

However, this is a custom function and I am neither accessing any other sheet/document. My access allows me to edit the sheet, though custom functions do not run as a given user and have some restrictions.

I did some research and found I could not run any of these commands. This is NOT exhaustive, just some of the data gathering functions I cannot run.

```
sheet.getLastColumn();
cell.getValue();
sheet.getRange(rangeParameters).getValues();
```

I can, however, use:

```
sheet.getRange(rangeParameters);
cell.getRow();
cell.getColumn();
```

So, in effective, I can create a range object, a cell object, a sheet object, but I cannot return any values. Odd also that I cannot get the last column (or last row) of a sheet but can get the row or column of a cell.

Again - the exact code runs perfectly on one sheet, fails on the other.

Due to the organization I work for I cannot share much more information. Suffice to say, all scripts and sheets allowed to run scripts to through an approval process. I work on the team that provides that access. Both spreadsheets have the same access granted.

I have not found anything limiting script access in the Workspace admin console. However, here is some code I wrote that works on one sheet, fails on the other.

```
function returnStatus(input) {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ws.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  const row = cell.getRow();
  const column = cell.getColumn();
  const cellVal = cell.getValue();  //FAILS HERE
  return row;
}
```

I've noted where it fails.

I'm curious if anyone knows why a custom function this simple would fail with that error. Are there Workspace settings that I'm missing?

Comment: I am unsure if this is the source of your problem (hence me not posting it as an answer), but in the code you provided you have the line `const cell = getActiveCell();`, which does not reference the sheet at all. Try replacing it with `sheet.getActiveCell()`

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I cannot copy between my personal system (this) and the company provided system. So, I typed the that over in error. But yes, it is not the source of the problem.

Comment: 1.`FAILS HERE` How do you know that? Provide screenshot of logs. 2. Global variables- what do you have outside this function?

Comment: I know it because the error is indicated in the cell where the custom function was placed. I can't do screen shots due to company policy. However, if I remove that line, it runs fine.

There is, at this point, no additional code in the sheet. However, I did place a function that does all of those failed functions as a regular function and it runs fine.

Comment: Note: On the spreadsheet cell where I place the custom function, it indicates the line number the script fails on.  That is exactly where it fails. If I remove the line it works. If I add another line that runs fine - and even make that new line the return value of the function, that value shows in the cell. If I add the failing line back in on another line, it fails with the new line number indicated.

Comment: It doesn't fail for me on one sheet and fails on another. I've used the same commands on other custom functions without issue, so, yes, I know it "should" work. Also, it only fails in the custom function. If I run the same commands in a standard function, they run fine.

Comment: How is the spreadheet shared?

Comment: Both sheets are shared to me as an editor. I can make changes directly in the sheet on any cell. There is no protection on either sheet. I can run scripts that perform all these functions, set values, and really perform any actions necessary. The exact same commands run in a regular (standalone) function. I ran it from the console and from a menu item I added. Both ran fine. It is solely in the custom function on one particular spreadsheet.

Comment: `cell.getValue()` is the active cell's value, which at this time would be `LOADING..`. Also, you can probably get that value can be derived from the argument `input`.

Comment: `Both sheets are shared to me as an editor.` Custom functions runs anonymously. So, your permissions doesn't matter much. Have you tried making the sheet public and seeing if that changes anything in the function's behavior?

Comment: I'm only showing that as an example of what isn't running. The custom function - which, again, works on another sheet, evaluates values in subsequent cells in the row and returns a value based on what is in those subsequent cells. However, I don't make it to that evaluative code as it requires me to get the values from the current column + 1 to the end of the sheet on that row. I can't run getLastRow() and I cannot run, range.getValues(); I can create the range.

Comment: I realize that custom functions do not run under my account. I was simply indicating that those commands do run under my account in a standard function. I cannot make the sheet public - I have the permissions to but  - again, company policy would not allow it. I may be able to work with the sheet owner on Tuesday. However, both sheets are shared to the same group and then to me. Exact same permissions.

Comment: The activeCell returns the  cell that the function is inserted into not the active cell on the sheet.

Comment: Yes.. and that is the desired effect. Based on the row/column of the activecell (the cell the formula is on) it evaluates subsequent values in the row. The parameter I pass on the custom function is the cell to the right to the end of the sheet. ie: if I am putting the function on G2, the input would be, H2:2  this ensures that changes to cells to the right will cause the custom function to refresh.

Comment: `I'm only showing that as an example of what isn't running` Just make sure the example is completely reproducible in a new project associated with that sheet. Maybe even delete the project(File> delete in legacy editor) and create a new project. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+You+do+not+have+permission+to+access+the+requested+document

Comment: I'll give that a try and see if it does anything. I won't be back on the system for a couple hours. Thanks.

Comment: So in some sense it can't return the value of the cell because it returns the value to the cell.

Comment: Found this [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/236501242) that may be related.

Comment: Well... deleting and recreating the project did not solve this. Hmm... I may need to re-create the Spreadsheets entirely, get corporate approval on the project (not problematic, my team grants the approval for running code), and re-point all the users to the new sheet. I'll look at a few things this morning and see what I can come up with.